# Dangerous to Assign Django Model Same Name as a Python Class?

Tags: python, django, django-models

When building a Django application, is it dangerous from a framework or namespace perspective to create a Python class that has the same name as one of your Django models?  My application uses a Python class called "Photo" to store temporary information about photos when my application is uploading them.  But after I process a photo, I want to store other permanent information about the photo to my database via a Photo model.  I know there's potential confusion from a programmer perspective.  But aside from that risk, if the class and model are in separate modules, am I likely to run into problems or encounter strange errors because Django gets confused as to which is which?

Thanks.

Comment: A model class is a class that temporary store data before save it to Database, why do you need another Photo class?

Comment: If you import the module and then use the full name in dot notation, you should be fine. Django also uses full names for dependency injection, so it shouldnt get confused.

Comment: Django shouldn't get confused with your definition, as long as you do the proper import. Also if you want to eliminate the confusion, you could use the syntax `from xyz import Photo as TempPhoto` or something similar, then use `TempPhoto` as your python `Photo` class name.

Comment: @Gocht I want separate data structures because they'll be holding different information.  Some of the data I save to the class doesn't need to be stored in the database.  It's just temporary processing information.

Comment: If you don't need to store some Photo instance, just do not call `.save()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an explicit reference to this fact, but you'll be fine. Keep in mind you still must follow the rules of Python, so you can't go importing name conflicts and such, but the models you are creating are themselves are subclasses of a class provided by Django, so it's not like internal functions of isinstance() would behave foolishly purely because of a similar name. When models are loaded by Django, they are indeed namespaced by app (as you can see in [accessing a model in a different app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), when dealing with [database routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) or by how the database tables are named. To get deeper, check out the source for [apps.registry](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/apps/registry.py) that ensures even model names between modules do not conflict, and [apps.config](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/apps/config.py) for the object that deals with importing names wrapped up in a module. All this registration and app loading is going to be completed before you even get into running a lot of your Django code (assuming you didn't inject it in the way of course). Also, I have done it, so no worries about Django being too foolish when it comes to class/model names.